# A question to query out the child's table with WHERE condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have facing a question in MVC with EntityFramework project. After study research, I using same way with example that working.
However, the output is not correct with my expected

```
        public List<School> GetSchoolDetails(EnumProvider firstProvider, EnumProvider secondProvider,  DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
        {
            using (myDB db = new myDB())
            {
                List<School> listSchool = new List<School>();

                listSchool = db.School
                    .Where(a => a.Date> fromDate
                    && a.Date < toDate
                    && a.Provider == firstProvider
                    || a.Provider == secondProvider
                    && a.Room.Any(b => b.Status == EnumStatus.ACCEPTED))
                    .ToList();

                return listSchool;
            }
        }
```

The relationship

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Student)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Room)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<School>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Room)
                .WithRequired(e => e.School)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.SchoolID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The output is not correct as I want the Status is Accepted from child's table (table Room). But the output of the list is contain all the status inside. Where the mistake I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are filtering the **parent** records based on child record criteria.

The child records outputted included will not be filtered unless you do something like a Select out with a where clause for Room which is a bit troublesome.

```
               List<School> listSchool = new List<School>();

                listSchool = db.School
                    .Where(a => a.Date> fromDate
                    && a.Date < toDate
                    && a.Provider == firstProvider
                    || a.Provider == secondProvider
                    && a.Room.Any(b => b.Status == EnumStatus.ACCEPTED))
                    .Select(a => new School
                    {
                       SchoolID = a.SchoolID,
                       SchoolName = a.SchoolName,
                       // ... other properties
                       Room = a.Room.Where(b => b.Status == EnumStatus.ACCEPTED)
                    }
                    .ToList();

                return listSchool;
```